# Mysterious programming language

Tags: programming-languages

I found some random code while cleaning out a server at work, no one seems to know what programming language it is.

There are no semi colons at the end of lines
It uses the keywords "if", "then", "for", "to", "do" but not "end"
It uses the keyword "as" so is probably Object Oriented

So far it looks like F# or Haskell syntax however

It also uses #0

We think this is Pascal-style notation for representing chars, so #0 would be the equivalent of '\0' in C

Any help would be great.

Below is an extract of the code.

```
bc=(ay*ax*az)
check1 = ((bc+bc)*(ax+acx)*(az+acz))
check2 = p_ar.count-9
if check1!=check2 then change(messagebox "rebuild")

--position
dmorr1=#0
dmar2=#0
dmar3=#0

--Y update
if acy>0 and bc
{
    dmar1=#0
    dmar2=#0
    rnum = (bp+ch)
    for i=1 to pcount do
    {
        if (sag m)!=0 then
        {
            append dmar2(getUserProp cnode("cp" + (i as string)))
        }
        else
        }
            append dmar2(getUserProp dconde("cp" + (i as string)))
            append imgt1 dmar2
            dmar2=#0
        }
```

Comment: Looks like 3ds MaxScript for 3ds, autodesk, etc.

Comment: Yup - it definitely looks like [MaxScript](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/MAXScript-Help/).  Q: Are you sure about the curly braces ("{}")?

Comment: If we replace the curly braces and zeros with brackets, with =#() being an empty array assignment, then MaxScript checks out.

I'll see what the others think on Monday, thanks a lot guys.

Comment: By the way I found your code being used in "Oreimo" anime http://i.imgur.com/IRkp1Ki.png

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like mentioned, looks like [MaxScript](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/MAXScript-Help/) for 3ds / AutoDesk. Always up for easy point gluttony :)